# Improve react&redux cordova app startup time

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs, redux

It seems my `bundle.js` slows down the initial load time of the app because its a heavy 5.1 MB big.
Is there a way to cleverly split the bundle into smaller fragments to speed up the load time?

Also I read that all Cordova plugins are loaded first before the `deviceready` event is fired. Wouldn't it be better if you could register for individual plugin load states and not have them all loaded synchronously on startup? I am thinking about loading on demand. Why load the camera or file system plugin when you never need it in certain initial states of the app?

Is there a `cordova.getPluginAsync` or similar?

Comment: Don't use a huge rendering library for mobile!

Comment: The app is going to use react&redux. There is no way around it.

Comment: Are you loading an initial screen with critical CSS inlined and fetching the rest of your resources asynchronously?

Comment: Re: _no way around it_, I am sorry for your users ;_;

Comment: I am not using any initial screen at the moment. That's why I am asking this question. How to split up bundles with webpack or browserify to make them load faster at startup. Did any of you guys read the question? The tags? I am not debating the "framework" used here. Otherwise I would write the app in C++. Fastest startup time and smallest memory footprint.

Comment: did you try compiling it with `NODE_ENV="production"`